# Convert HTML page to PDF in asp.net.cor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html-to-pdf

I want to pass the Viewbag to the PrintCertification view while using ViewAsPdf

the problem is when the view is running the viewbag is not apear

The controller of PrintCertification code

```
    public IActionResult PrintCertification(String UserName , String ActivityName )
       {

           ViewBag.UserName = UserName;
           ViewBag.ActivityName = ActivityName;

           return new ViewAsPdf("PrintCertification")
           {
               PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
           };
       }



The View of PrintCertification which I want to make as a pdf file  


   <html>
   <head>
       <h1 id="CA" style="align-content:center">Certificate of Apperciation</h1>

   </head>
   <body  class="bg" style="background-image: url(https://localhost:44387/Screenshot.png); ">
       <h3 id="TC">The College of Medicine at King Faisal University would like to thank</h3>
       <h1 id="name">@ViewBag.UserName</h1>
       <h3 id="content">
           For his valuable participation as ( a leader/an organizer) in the (campaign/ activity/ course) of <br>( the name of the activity), that aims to ( aim of the activity).<br>
           Targeting (target audience).<br>
           Held in ( place), On (Date).
       </h3>
       <h4 id="Dr">Dr. Naif Mohammed Alhmam</h4>
       <h4 id="OS">Official Seal</h4>
       <h4 id="VD">Vice-dean for development <br>and community partnership</h4>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can be done this easily.just follow this link:-https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-pdf-in-asp-net-core-mvc-using-rotativa-aspnetcore/  just install ```rotativa``` in your application by following this link.and after that you can done this easily.

Comment: @PritomSarkar  How I can pass viewdata or viewbag to the view

Comment: https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/aspnetcore/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-vs-session-vs-cookies follow this link.

Comment: @PritomSarkar see now the description of the question I make some update